# PHP Get Array key with Value

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to get the array key of every input type that has value.

Please see below my code

```
<form action="welcome.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="ptotal_monthly_fee[]" >
<input type="text" name="ptotal_monthly_fee[]" value"1">
<input type="text" name="ptotal_monthly_fee[]" >
<input type="text" name="ptotal_monthly_fee[]" value"2">
<input type="text" name="ptotal_monthly_fee[]" >
<input type="submit">

</form>
```

This is welcome.php

```
<?php

$count = array_keys($_POST['ptotal_monthly_fee']);

foreach ($count as $value) {
  echo "$value <br>";
}
?>
```

My Output is:
0
1
2
3
4

I want my output to be:
1
3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to check the values in the posted array and then echo the corresponding key if the value is not empty:

```
foreach ($_POST['ptotal_monthly_fee'] as $key => $value) {
    if (!empty($value)) echo "$key <br>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$stmt = '';
if(isset($_POST['ptotal_monthly_fee'])){
  foreach($_POST['ptotal_monthly_fee'] as $key => $value){
    if($value !== ''){
      $stmt .= "Key: $key<br>";
    }    
  }
}
```

Echo out $stmt in html

```
<?=$stmt?>
```

NOTE: in your code your value is not set in your inputs. Should be `value="1"`/`value="3"`